# make the div stay at he top when scrolled

Tags: html, css

I have a div element

```
 <div  className={ "flexRow alignItemsCenter margBot10 justifyContentSpaceBetween margTop24" } >
                  <h2 className="dialog__title subheading-text-medium fontMedium">Galley No:&nbsp;&nbsp;{airCraftLoadingSel.galley}</h2>
          </div>
```

i need to make this div stay at the top when  i scroll down to see more content .i have tried applying style={{position:sticky}} in the div but doesn't seems to give me the desired output.what else could be done.

Comment: `position: sticky` needs a `top` or `bottom` property to work. See the 2nd sentence in the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Add that and you're golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the `div` element stay at the top of the page when scrolling, you can try setting the `position` property to fixed and adjusting the top property to make sure it's positioned correctly. Here's code example

```
 <div style={{position: "fixed", top: 0, zIndex: 1, width: "100%"}} className={ "flexRow alignItemsCenter margBot10 justifyContentSpaceBetween margTop24" } >
                  <h2 className="dialog__title subheading-text-medium fontMedium">Galley No:&nbsp;&nbsp;{airCraftLoadingSel.galley}</h2>
          </div>
```

Write the code above it's reactjs if not you can write the style without the "" and at the end you should have ;, and it should have only the {} not two {{}}.
I hope this answers your question.